# VSCode プレーンテキストでのアウトラインを行いたい

Tags: vscode

おそらく機能拡張を自前で書かないといけないような気がしているのですが、VSCodeで.mdの拡張子をもつMarkDownファイルを編集しているときは、アウトラインが表示されて便利なのですが、これを .txt のプレーンテキストファイルに対してもアウトライン表示したいと思っています。

プレーンテキストを開いているときに
[1]自分で決めたルールでアウトラインのツリー構造が動くようにしたい
[2]MarkDownの定義に従ったアウトラインのツリー構造が動くようにしたい

おそらく、[1]は難しく、[2]は簡単な気がしていますが、現在のところ、[1]も[2]もやり方がわかりません。

どちらかやり方をご存知のかた、ヒントやリンクでもかまいませんのでよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [1]自分で決めたルールでアウトラインのツリー構造が動くようにしたい

そのルールが一般的なものでない限り、自作のプラグインを作成するしかないでしょう。

## [2]MarkDownの定義に従ったアウトラインのツリー構造が動くようにしたい

現在のファイルの言語モードを、自動判定されたものではなく手動で変更する機能があるようです。

> ステータスバーの言語インジケータをクリックし、表示されるドロップダウンリストから利用したい言語を選択する。
>   または、`Ctrl+K-M`でも同様の操作が可能。
>   https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file

Comment: なるほど！開くたびに Markdownに切り替えれば、プレーンテキストでも Markdown 系で書いておけば アウトラインできますね。

Answer (score 1):

[1]に関しては、VSCodeのアウトラインビュー機能の元になった？参考にした？エクステンションの、そのものの配布は終了していますが、ソースがまだ公開されているので、それを基にカスタマイズするということが考えられます。

一から作るのは大変でも、動いた実績のあるものを改造するのは何とかなりそうなレベルでは？

[Code Outline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline)

[patrys/vscode-code-outline](https://github.com/patrys/vscode-code-outline)